# Why the (Angular 13) component selector won't show as dropdown form?

Tags: angular, typescript

When i place a "dropdown-menu" form directly in the "dropdown" div it shows with no problems, but when i put the same form in a separate component and place the selector for that component, the dropdown won't "read" the same piece of code. Is there something i'm missing to add??
Here's my code of the dropdown and the separate component.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
     <h2 role="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"
      data-bs-auto-close="outside">Ricerca per Filtri</h2>
      <app-filtri-ricerca></app-filtri-ricerca>
</div>

// app-filtri-ricerca contains the following form

<div class="dropdown-menu" id="drp" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
                    <form class="px-4 py-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleDropdownFormEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormEmail1"
                                placeholder="email@example.com">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleDropdownFormPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormPassword1"
                                placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="dropdownCheck">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="dropdownCheck">
                                Remember me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-item">Cerca</div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: Are you having any error message?

Comment: Yes, the following:"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'."

Comment: I suppose the problem is the additional element tag of the new component (you insert a new level this way). You might be able to solve this by using an `attribute selector` on the child component instead of a component selector => `selector: '[app-child-component]'`